# Update UIButton title with string variable

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, ipad

I am trying to update the title of a button programmatically with an integer that has been converted to a string and having some trouble.  Here is what I have...

```
NSString *buttonText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", clickUp];
[myButton setTitle:@"%i" forState:UIControlStateNormal, buttonText];
```

Doing this gives me the error of "Too many arguments to method call, expected 2 have 3".  If I set the title manually it works fine.

Can you pass a string to a button title, if so, can someone share with me how?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your second line of code, do this:

```
[myButton setTitle:buttonText forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[myButton setTitle:@"%i" forState:UIControlStateNormal, buttonText];
```

should be

```
[myButton setTitle:buttonText forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

You already declared `buttonText` to be an `NSString*`, so the string literal is not necessary.  And besides, it's the literal for an integer.  An object, if you wanted to get technical, uses the literal %@, which would look like this:

```
[myButton setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", buttonText] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```